# semantic-ui-react - Menu.Item click triggers component render twice

Tags: reactjs, render, semantic-ui-react

Learning react and using `semantic-ui-react Menu` to build a SideBarMenu , and have below Questions

- How does clicking on a `Menu.Item`  trigger parent component (SBMenu) `render` ?
  like render on component is triggered either due to `change in state or props` , but what is changing for SBMenu ?
- Why is SBMenu `render` function called twice ?

```
Rendering .... future
Rendering .... future
```

**SidebarMenu**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Sidebar, Menu, Segment, Icon } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import SBMenu from './SBMenu'
import './SidebarMenu.css';
import SBRoutes from './SBRoutes'


const menuItems = [
    { icon: 'dashboard', label: 'Future ITEM', name: 'future', url: '/future' },
    { icon: 'dashboard', label: 'Future ITEM1', name: 'future', url: '/future1' }
  ];

class SidebarMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleItemClick = this.handleItemClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleItemClick () {
      console.log('item clicked')
  }

  /*shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return true;
  }*/

  render() {
    console.log("SidebarMenu called....")

    return (
      <Sidebar.Pushable as={Segment} className="SidebarMenu">
        <Sidebar
          as={Menu}
          borderless
          animation="push"
          icon="labeled"
          inverted
          onHide={this.handleSidebarHide}
          vertical
          visible={true}
          width="thin"
        >

        <SBMenu menuItems={menuItems} />

        </Sidebar>
        <Sidebar.Pusher>
          <div className="container">
             <SBRoutes />
          </div>
        </Sidebar.Pusher>
      </Sidebar.Pushable>
    );
  }
}


export default SidebarMenu;
```

**SBMenu**

```
class SBMenu extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }


  render() {
    const {location,menuItems} = this.props;
    console.log("Rendering .... " + location.pathname)
    return (menuItems.map((item, index) => (
            <Menu.Item
            name={item.name}
            as={Link}
            to={item.url}
            active={location.pathname === item.url}
            data-menu={item.label}
            key={`menu_item_${index}`}
            >
                    <Icon name={item.icon} />
                    {item.label}
            </Menu.Item>
        ))
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(SBMenu);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change child state from parent using lifting state up. You can simply pass a method to the SBMenu and work with it.

SBMenu render twice because you use the same name in menuItems.

It should be working fine now if you change menuItems name.

Comment: Thanks @Estiak for the response , renamed the other one as ```future1``` , still see render c alled twice